# Remote upload with a CCK file field

Tags: entities

How can use a CCK file field for uploading a file to another server?

- Without leaving the Drupal site, the end users click on the file field's "Browse" button.
- They browse for a file on is local computer.
- They click on the "Upload" button.
- The file is uploading to a remote server.

Comment: is the remote server running drupal?

Comment: Do you want the file to go to another website?  A CDN?  If you want to set up a CDN, look at the CDN module.

Comment: i have music website users upload mp3 files , i have a server for hosting mp3 files . i want when a user upload a file file saved in second server. i can use cdn for this?